# Purpose of WCF mocking

Tags: c#, wcf, unit-testing

I am having difficulties while trying to understand the purpose of mocking my WCF applications in unit tests. I have read this article [Testing with mock objects](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/686935/Unit-testing-with-Mock-objects-Rhino-Mocks) and I believe I got the idea why we use mocking in standard application -  it is better to test behaviour rather than implementation of the method. So with using Mock objects, I can test whether certain method called certain mock object, whether it changed some properties etc.

But while I was searching for some good ways how to test WCF, everyone was suggesting to use Mocking as well. The thing is, that I feel like I should test whether method (which is communication with service) is really able to reach the service and obtain result, that is satisfactory...which is not the case I will achieve using mock object.

### Question:

- Is using mock objects in my WCF app unit tests really intended to test only whether the method tried to call the OperationContract(method) exposed by service (while not expecting the real results)?

Or am I missing something?

Comment: "The thing is, that I feel like I should test whether method (which is communication with service) is really able to reach the service and obtain result" - you might want to look up integration testing. 
Unit tests on the other hand are fast, gives RTI and should notify you when your code breaks.

Comment: Hello Lews, yes I have stumbled upon integration tests as well, but still, almost every article suggest unit tests rather than integration tests...thats why I am confused.

Comment: You should have both, if possible. Unit tests to guide your design/code. Integration tests or end to end testing as such.

Comment: Consider separating your _service hosting technology_ (WCF) from the actual technology-agnostic _service processing logic_ (a plain assembly which knows nothing about WCF). [SOA Patterns](http://www.soapatterns.org/).  Then it's easy to mock both

Comment: Hello Micky. I am not sure whether I fully understand what you mean by the separation, but I will take a look at that link you provided. Thank you¨

Comment: @JakubJ Essentially, take your IIS-hosted WCF assembly and split in two. One just for the IIS+WCF bits (service class; WCF attributes; WCF behaviours etc) and the other just for pure logic. The latter is context-neutral and invokable 2 by non-WCF inc unit tests.  [1. Service Loose Coupling](http://serviceorientation.com/serviceorientation/service_loose_coupling); [2. Service-Orientation Principles with Java Web-Based Services](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2231780&seqNum=3); [3. Service loose coupling principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_loose_coupling_principle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of Unit Testing is not to test your application, but to make sure the code you've written is doing what is intended and subsequently let you know when you've made a simple coding goof. When it comes to testing for communication-based services, there are a dozen other factors, not the least of which being actual connectivity, that could affect your connection but not actually tell you anything useful about your code. Thus, you should rely on running debug runs of your application to test end-to-end functionality, and Unit Tests with those mocks to test the actual code functionality.

Will you miss something here and there? Yes, but the definition of good Unit Tests is such that you'll eventually have to touch them up when this happens.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So as Lews said in comments, is it good idea to have unit tests to check for simple coding mistakes and then implement robust integration tests, that will cover the communication between client and service?

Comment: Unit Test are for coding mistakes. I personally prefer to handle robust tests by running through everything by hand, but if you prefer to automate then yes, a robust test is advisable

Comment: So far, I have tested everything by hand, but as the application gets more and more options, it is getting a little bit time consuming to test it. But again, thanks for your help.